# Calculating MSE from 2 Tensors

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the mean squared error (MSE) from two numpy arrays that are later turned into tensors. I'm getting back a value of 36909.2148
This seems very high... Does this look accurate?

```
import numpy as np
import torch

w = torch.randn(2, 3, requires_grad=True) #total weight
b = torch.randn(2, requires_grad=True) #total bias

def model(x):
    return x @ w.t() + b

inputs = np.array([[73, 67, 43],
              [91, 88, 64],
              [87, 134, 58],
              [102, 43, 37],
              [69, 96, 70]], dtype='float32')

preds = model(torch.from_numpy(inputs))

targets = np.array([[56, 70],
                [81, 101],
                [119, 133],
                [22, 37],
                [103, 119]], dtype='float32')

targets_ = torch.from_numpy(targets)

def mse(preds, targets_):
    loss = ((targets_ - preds)**2).mean()

    return loss

# Uncomment the following lines to test
print(mse(preds, targets_))
```

Comment: presume `torch` is from a module.  which one please ?

Comment: The module is pytorch.

Comment: You're computing the L2 loss between the two tensors. I don't really see the meaning of this question...

Comment: I'm confused as to what I should set x equal to (the parameter for the model() function). Should x be some random tensor that I create? Should I use the model() function on the targets array when converting to a tensor like I did when converting the inputs array to the preds tensor?